# search for all fields which have some string in field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

How can I get only results for specific fields where field name is like something ?

fx.
get all fields which have "status" in their field name.
I tried this but It doesnt work:
sta*
I want also to do later this: 
sta* OR STA* OR Sta*

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Some formatting as Code might already be enough to make your question good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is using following:

```
 | fieldsummary  sta* STA* Sta*
```

Answer (score 0):

Entering just "status" in the search box may not be enough.  It depends on what your default indexes are and where the data is.  By default, the default index is 'main', but your admins may have put the data in different indexes.  Using `index=* status` for a 15-minute search should tell you which index holds the data.  Then you can specify it in your subsequent searches.

Comment: This is not the answer of the question.